# 10 picture HTML and JavaScript slideshow not showing all pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, slideshow

Only up to 4 pictures are showing up in the slideshow, the previous button does the same thing

Java:

```js
imgArray = new Array(10);
imgArray[0] = new Image;
imgArray[0].src = "Euclid.png";
imgArray[1] = new Image;
imgArray[1].src = "Pythagoras.png";
imgArray[2] = new Image;
imgArray[2].src = "Fibonacci.png";
imgArray[3] = new Image;
imgArray[3].src = "Descartes.png";
imgArray[4] = new Image;
imgArray[4].src = "Fermat.png";
imgArray[5] = new Image;
imgArray[5].src = "Pascal.png";
imgArray[6] = new Image;
imgArray[6].src = "Newton.png";
imgArray[7] = new Image;
imgArray[7].src = "Leibniz.png";
imgArray[8] = new Image;
imgArray[8].src = "Euler.png";
imgArray[9] = new Image;
imgArray[9].src = "Gauss.jpg";
index = 0;

function doPrevious()
{
    if (index > 0)
    {
        index--;
        document.slideshow.src = imgArray[index].src;
    }
    return;
}

function doNext()
{
    if (index < 9)
    {
        index++;
        document.slideshow.src = imgArray[index].src;
    }
    return;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "en">

<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Mathmeticians Slide Show</title>
<script src = "MathSlide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<noscript>JavaScript Not Enabled!</noscript>
<h1>My Mathmetician Slide Show!!!</h1>
<br>
<img src="Euclid.png" name = "slideshow" height = "500" width = "300">
<a href = "javascript:doPrevious()">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "javascript:doNext()">Next</a>&nbsp;
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry i couldnt include the images of the mathematicians.
The slideshow only goes up to Descartes and thats it

Basically I have folder with all 10 of the pictures, the html file and the JavaScript file. What i thought the code would do was search from the html file to look for the JS file though i guess i was wrong

Comment: Running your code results in `ReferenceError: imgArray is not defined`. It also appears to lack a `imgArray[0] = new Image;` that all the other array indexes have.

Comment: @ceejayoz woops forgot to copy that into to the post my bad

Comment: OK, now you probably want to give your `img` tag an `id`, and use `document.getElementById()` to fetch it. I don't think `document.slideshow` is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your logic is because of your use of `document.slideshow`, which does not exist. You need to target your `img` element in the DOM, using methods such as `querySelector()` or `getElementById()` for example, then you can update its `src` to match the given index.

Here's a working example. Also note that I made some amendments to the logic to better meet current best practices - eg. avoiding putting JS method references in `href` or `onclick` attributes, and simplifying the logic to keep `index` within the bounds of the array. Note that I also set the `alt` of the images so you can see that they are being changed.

```js
const slideshow = document.querySelector('#slideshow');
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');
const next = document.querySelector('#next');
let index = 0;

prev.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  index = Math.max(--index, 0);
  updateSlideshow(index);
});

next.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  index = Math.min(++index, imgArray.length -1);
  updateSlideshow(index);
})

const updateSlideshow = (idx) => {
  slideshow.src = imgArray[idx].src;
  slideshow.alt = imgArray[idx].src;
}

// build your Image() array as required:
const imgArray = [];
imgArray[0] = new Image;
imgArray[0].src = "Euclid.png";
imgArray[1] = new Image;
imgArray[1].src = "Pythagoras.png";
imgArray[2] = new Image;
imgArray[2].src = "Fibonacci.png";
imgArray[3] = new Image;
imgArray[3].src = "Descartes.png";
imgArray[4] = new Image;
imgArray[4].src = "Fermat.png";
imgArray[5] = new Image;
imgArray[5].src = "Pascal.png";
imgArray[6] = new Image;
imgArray[6].src = "Newton.png";
imgArray[7] = new Image;
imgArray[7].src = "Leibniz.png";
imgArray[8] = new Image;
imgArray[8].src = "Euler.png";
imgArray[9] = new Image;
imgArray[9].src = "Gauss.jpg";
```

```css
#slideshow {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Mathmetician Slide Show!!!</h1>
<img src="Euclid.png" id="slideshow" />
<a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Comment: im having errors still. Its still only showing the first 4 images, could it just be problem with my files/folders?